# 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, typeerror

I have Dataframe of "IMDB data from 2006 to 2016" which is in Kaggle site: https://www.kaggle.com/PromptCloudHQ/imdb-data .
I have made it as numpy array but when I want to assign the inner product of two row of it to numpy.float64 variable, it gives me this error:

```
sim[i][1] = np.inner(vec[i],vec[1])
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

here is my code:

```
X = trainset.drop(['Description', 'Runtime','Director','Title', 'ID'], axis=1)
X.Revenue = X.Revenue.fillna(X.Revenue.mean())
X.Metascore= X.Metascore.fillna(X.Revenue.min())
features = ['Genre','Actors']
for f in features:
    X_dummy = X[f].str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix(f + '.')
    X = X.drop([f], axis = 1)
    X = pd.concat((X, X_dummy), axis = 1)
vec = np.ones((1000,2422), dtype=np.uint8)
vec = X.values
sim = np.ones((1000,1), dtype=np.float64)
for i in range (1,1000):
    sim[i][1] = np.inner(vec[i],vec[1])
```

and when I get the type of this inner product it gives me exactly this type:

```
>>chi = np.inner(vec[0],vec[0])
>>print(type(chi))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: Ca you add some smple data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: `vec = np.array((1000,2422), dtype=np.uint8)`, `sim = np.array((1000,1), dtype=np.float64)` are these tuples supposed to be the shapes of the arrays? If so, you are using them wrong. Use the `shape` argument in a populated array like `np.ones` or `np.zeros`.

Comment: @jezrael HI jezrael! yes but I'm new and I had a little problem with link or photo uploading but I use the data of this link:
(https://www.kaggle.com/PromptCloudHQ/imdb-data)

Comment: @user2285236 yes I tried with these form too  but I get this same error.

Comment: @user2285236 the problem was the complex variable which I miss them but with the **np.array** it did not solved and I used **np.ones** as you told, do you know why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find how this problem happened, I have assigned float variable to my array but when I used *fillna* with *mean* function and after that in inner product it returns some **complex** variable so I changed the array type to this form:

```
sim = np.ones((1000,1), dtype=np.complex_)
```

and the problem was solved.